# How to avoid duplicate data while Importing for particular field in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Is there possiblity to avoid duplicate data while Importing 100 or 200 records in CRM 2011

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is possibly a bit broad, the essential answer is yes.

You could write plugins, but that is probably unnecessary. Duplicate detection rules can be configured to run on create/update.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309427.aspx)

You define fields to try to match on and activate the rule, which will then cause an exception to be thrown when trying to import data.

Comment: thx for the info... but is it possible while importing data as XML etc....customization CRM 2011

Comment: I'm sorry not sure I understand the question.. can you try to explain inyour question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible to detect or avoid duplicates in CRM while importing data as XML. This can be done by : 
There are already existing duplication detection rules available in the CRM by default or You can create your own custom duplicate detection rules according to your requirement.This will surely detect your duplicate data.